# How can you do algebra with rounded numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a series of seemingly simple algebra problems:

```
 9*x = 5,
 5*x = 4,
 4*x = 3,
 1*x = 1
```

and

```
22*x = 12,
12*x = 7,
7*x = 6,
6*x = 2,
2*x = 2
```

However I [cannot find a solution for this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=22*x%20%3D%2012%2C%2012*x%20%3D%207%2C%207*x%20%3D%206%2C%206*x%20%3D%202) because the answers are not exactly 12, 7 etc. They've been rounded to the nearest whole number (0.5 rounds up). The number being multiplied by x is the (rounded) number of the answer in the line above.

Note: that anything under 0.5 will be increased to 0.5 (and then rounded to 1)

So my first question is how can one do algebra with rounded results?

Also is there a way to do this in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I don't really follow you. There is no solution to 22*x = 12, 12*x = 7, 7*x = 6, 6*x = 2 because x can't be both 12/22 and 7/12, not because of any rounding.

Comment: Your rounded equations give you constraints, $\frac{4.5}{9} \leqslant x < \frac{5.5}{9}$ etc. Combine the constraints from the rounded equations.

Comment: @avid19 Maybe I wasn't clear, the 2nd line uses the answer from the previous line so 22(maybe rounded)*x=12(rounded) and then the next one would be 12(rounded)*x = 7(rounded), does that make it possible now?

Comment: I think I am not being very clear, the numbers I've written are not the actual numbers, for example where it says 7x = 6 it is actualy: (6.5-7.49999) * x = (5.5-6.49999). Like it can be any number in that range, it just rounds to 7 and 6

Comment: @DanielFischer How can I combine them?

Comment: If you write the constraints corresponding to the "equations" in the form $a_i \le x \le b_i$, then the result is $\max(a_i) \le x \le \min(b_i)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael doing that I get 0.7<=x<0.61. I think the problem occurs because the left hand side is also rounded, ie instead of 4.5/9 <= x < 5.5/9, the denominator is also a rounded value, how would I do it in this case?

Comment: If both sides of the equation $9x=5$ are rounded, you get the constraint $4.5/9.5 < x < 5.5/8.5$. This works as long as both coefficients are positive.

Comment: @Rahul thanks, this gives me 0.6363636 < x < 0.640588, is there any way to narrow it down further?

Comment: Also it didn't work because 9*0.636 would round to 6 not 5